# Profile Java CPU load

Tags: java, profiling

I need to profile the CPU load of a commercial Java app, of which I don't have the source.

I can see that the app is CPU bound, but how can I understand if the CPU is busy doing FP operations, integers operations, or something else?

If I could find a typical load I could use some open source benchmark tools to simulate the load on different HardWare platform, to understand which CPU offers me the best value, which is my ultimate goal.

Comment: you can introspect using a tool like jprobe/ jprofiler - that will show you which methods/ operations are being invoked and what eats up time and memory. they may not do CPU per se though, but surely you could look at sar/ top/ mpstat for that purpose (i.e. wherever the CPU jumps up, take a snapshot)?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using JDK 1.6.x, I highly recommend jvisualvm, which is an executable in $JAVA_HOME/bin.

This will help you identify your CPU bottleneck, although if you don't have the source you'll have limited ability to address the underlying issue.

Comment: You either need to download the JDK (not the JRE) or the stand-alone version of jvisualvm.  It can attach to a running program!  Requires Oracle JVM.

Answer (score 3):

The JProfiler program (commercial software) http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html served me well. (2-3 years ago. But the software should still be good :))

Answer (score 1):

I've been using dynaTrace produciton edition and it help me a lot. Low overhead, high visibility into CPU and Memory bottlenecks.

I do recommend dynaTrace.